# Break an infinite loop when a function returns True

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a code set up which, if it works, will stop a while loop when a nested function eventually returns True. However, every time I have attempted to test it at this phase, it doesn't seem to reach an end.

The goal of the current program is to simulate the Haunt Roll mechanic in *Betrayal at House on the Hill* and *Betrayal at Baldur's Gate*, and simulate an experiment to determine how many Omen rooms will be found before beginning the Haunt. The next phase will be to set up an array and for loop to show the respective probabilities of each game length.

```
import random as rd

import numpy as np


Betrayald6 = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2],dtype='int')

def fairdicesum(dice):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(dice.shape[0]):
        single = rd.choice(dice[i,:])
        sum = sum + single
    return sum

def HauntRoll(CurseCount, Game = 'House on the Hill'):
    if Game == 'House on the Hill':
        dice = np.zeros([6,6])
    elif Game == "Baldur's Gate":
        dice = np.zeros([CurseCount,6])
    else:
        print ('No dice')
    for i in range(len(dice)):
        dice[i] = Betrayald6
    Roll = fairdicesum(dice)
    if Game == 'House on the Hill':
        if Roll < CurseCount:
            Haunt = 1
        else:
            Haunt = 0
    elif Game == "Baldur's Gate":
        if Roll < 6:
            Haunt = 0
        else:
            Haunt = 1
        return Haunt

def HowLongToHaunt(Game = 'House on the Hill'):
    CurseCount = 0
    while True:
        CurseCount = CurseCount + 1
        Result = HauntRoll(CurseCount,Game=Game)
        if Result == 1:
            break
    return CurseCount
```

I have tested the `fairdicesum` function and the `HauntRoll` function, and both of them work. Is there a way to improve the code for the `HowLongToHaunt` function so that it will run more efficiently?

As an aside, this is my first time using a while loop, as opposed to a for loop, so it may be an issue with the loop, though I'm not getting an error message.

Comment: As an aside, are you using 0 and 1 instead of an actual boolean value? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: If Game == 'House on the Hill' then HauntRoll will return None. Perhaps the return is not indented correctly.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks! It actually was indented too far. Nice catch!

Comment: You’re welcome. We are here to help. (btw **do** consider returning boolean values from HauntRoll)

Comment: I originally had HauntRoll outputting Boolean; I've switched it back. The reason was because having True negate the loop seemed a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is you are only returning a value if the game is "Baldur's Gate".

Move the `return Haunt` out of the `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to make this run more efficiently is to replace

```
def HowLongToHaunt(Game = 'House on the Hill'):
    CurseCount = 0
    while True:
        CurseCount = CurseCount + 1
        Result = HauntRoll(CurseCount,Game=Game)
        if Result == 1:
            break
    return CurseCount
```

with

```
def HowLongToHaunt(Game = 'House on the Hill'):
    CurseCount = 0
    while Result != 1:
        CurseCount = CurseCount + 1
        Result = HauntRoll(CurseCount,Game=Game)
    return CurseCount
```

Comment: There’s no efficiency gained here.